# What is this mark for "? function()"

Tags: php, plugin-development, array

I was working through someone else's code trying to understand their plugin so I could combine it with another plugin to do something different. I have no clue why this question mark is here in the middle of this entry. The code appears as such in one line:

`$variable = !empty( $_POST['variable_b'] )  ? explode( "\n", trim( $_POST['variable_b'] ) ) : array();`

I understand what the empty, explode, and trim functions do here. I assume that is all being amended to the array. The question mark almost seems like a mini conditional statement.

Comment: use web search to check 'php ternary operator'

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. I was looking through all the PHP stuff I could find and couldn't get this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called Ternary Operator.

```
if( ! empty( $_POST['variable_b'] ) {
    $variable = explode( "\n", trim( $_POST['variable_b'] );
} else {
    $variable = array();
}
```

You can see [PHP Shorthand If/Else Using Ternary Operators (?:)](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)  for more details.